# Konsole: Remote tab title show current directory?

Tags: konsole

Is there a way I can configure the remote tab title of a Konsole window to show the current directory as my tab title? Is there a way I can use the `%w` option to configure it as such?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. You can use your shell config to render text in place of %w.

I added the following line to the zshrc file in the server I ssh'd to have a shortened version of pwd act as the tab title with the %w option.

```
DISABLE_AUTO_TITLE="true" 
function precmd () {
   window_title="\033]0;${PWD##*/}\007"
   echo -ne "$window_title"
 }
```